# Add Vue click event to HTML string fetched via API

Tags: vue.js, electron

I have some HTML string that I get via API. Let’s say it looks like:

```
const msg = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="www.google.com">google</a>
             consectetur adipiscing elit <a href="www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
             lorem ipsum.'
```

Now I need to add Vues @click event on those a elements. Is it possible to parse somehow the string and add the Vue event on it and output it?

Basically I have an electron app and I want to some additional logic on the links other then redirect.

Comment: I am assuming the html string does not contain only the a tags, right? If not, my only suggestion would be to parse it for a tags and add to the string a string representation of what you want done.

Comment: @tomerpacific it's just text with `a` HTML elements. I tried that what you suggest but I can't add the parsed content via `v-html` because then the @click doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use v-html here. You can parse the string easily using `node-html-parser`. Then you can use a `v-for` to show the html

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-cache-50hum?file=/src/App.vue:0-1036)

Code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>a tags go below</div>
    <div v-for="(tag, key) of a_tags" :key="key">
      <a :href="tag.attributes.href">{{ tag.text}}</a>
    </div>
    <button @click="showTags">show tags</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

import { parse } from "node-html-parser";

const msg =
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="www.google.com">google</a> consectetur adipiscing elit <a href="www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a> lorem ipsum.';
const tags = parse(msg);

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(tags);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      a_tags: [tags.childNodes[1], tags.childNodes[3]]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showTags() {
      console.log(this.a_tags);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response - works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT AFTER CHECKING THE FIDDLE:**

It seems that appending the refs to the string is not working, therefore, you should put a `ref` to the parent as follows:

```
<div id="app">
   <div v-html="msg" ref="msg">
   </div>
</div>
```

And then add the event to each of its two children in this case as follows:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
            msg: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="www.google.com">google</a> consectetur adipiscing elit <a href="www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a> lorem ipsum.'
  },
  mounted() {
      this.$refs.msg.children[0].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('foo')
      };

      this.$refs.msg.children[1].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('bar')
      };
  }
})
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. _Cannot read property '$el' of undefined_ - https://jsfiddle.net/63udfth9/